# Access to Videos library iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk

are there access to "Videos" library iPhone sdk(not to Photos)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, look up ALAssetsLibrary in the docs.

An instance of ALAssetsLibrary represents the videos and photos that are under the control of the Photos application.

The library includes those that are in the saved photos album, those coming from iTunes and those that were directly imported into the device. You use it to retrieve the list of all asset groups and to save images and videos into the Saved Photos album.

You create an instance of ALAssetsLibrary using alloc and init:

Comment: i mean not Photos. me need video form Videos(there are films...)

Answer (score 1):

here you can find a bunch of useful videos

http://developer.apple.com/videos/iphone/#video-essentials-intro